# Can _Layout plus a partial view be specified in _ViewStart.cshtml of an MVC3 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor, razorgenerator

I have a suite of several MVC3 web applications, all of which reference a common Core.dll. I have compiled common views using RazorGenerator, and the subscribing sites find the relevant views from the pre-compiled .dll without any problem.

I am trying to do the same for the layout page, as this is common across all the sites too, save for one or two divs that are specific to that particular site. This also works fine, in as much as the _layout view is served up by just doing this:

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

But, to get the site specific divs in the layout populated, I want to have a partial view in the specific site and use JQuery to set the HTML of the placeholding div in the _layout. Something like:

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

//Have a hidden div containing the partial view that sits in the specific site
<div id="SiteSpecificStuff" style="display:none">
    @Html.Partial("_SiteSpecificStuff", model)
</div>

// Use jQuery to populate the html of the placeholding div on the _Layout 
// with that of the partial view
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#divPlaceHolderOnLayout")
                        .html($("SiteSpecificStuff").html());
    });

</script>
```

I have tried this but the _ViewStart does not re-fire on every post. Is this possible using a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
@RenderSection("YouSection", required: false)
```

Comment: Should this be added to the _ViewStart?

Comment: To your layout (_Layout.cshtml)